# Change variables beetween urls and view

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

Is this possible to change variable after it's been catched by url dispatcher and pass it to view changed?

For example:
I've got following urlpattern

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^articles/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'article.views.article_view'),
)
```

I want to change `article_id` before passing it to `article.views.article_view`

I need this, as an override. I've got `article` app which can't be changed, but I must use it. :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a wrapper view. Map the URL to your own view which then calls  `article.views.article_view`. You can then change whatever you want within you wrapper view.

Example:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^articles/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'article_wrapper.wrap_article_view'),
)
```

In `article_wrapper.py`:

```
import article
def wrap_article_view(request, article_id):
    article_id = modify_it(article_id)
    return article.views.article_view(request, article_id)
```

#### Update:

If you need to do the same `article_id` translation for several views, you can probably make the wrapper more generic. Example:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^articles/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 
        view='article_wrapper.generic_article_wrapper',
        kwargs={'view_name':'article_view'}
    ),
)
```

and in `article_wrapper.py`:

```
import article
def generic_article_wrapper(request, article_id, view_name=None):
    article_id = modify_it(article_id)
    try:
        view = get_attr(article.views, view_name)
    except AttributeError:
        # handle invalid view name
    return view(request, article_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from article.views import article_view

def my_article_view(request, article_id):
    my_id = article_id * 2 # modify your id
    return article_view(request, my_id)
```